# Can individuality be copied?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, mind-body

Let's do a thought experiment, You are sleeping in a sensory deprivation tank 1, there is another tank next to you let's call it tank 2. Now there is a hypothetical machine M, which is a Universal 3-D printer, meaning that it can copy your "state" and paste it into tank 2 within a femtosecond (the unit of time doesn't matter).

So now this entails a few options:

1. Such a machine can't exist because either there is a physical property that "defines" your state that can't be copied, or there is a physical constraint that makes the construction of such a machine impossible.
2. "You" are somehow correlated with your enviroment, making it impossible for the machine to copy you without copying the enviroment, thus the entire universe.
3. You can be copied. But either of these three things can happen: a) You can "switch" between these two bodies in tank 1 and tank 2, like switching between characters in a game b) You can't "switch" meaning there is some loss of information in the copying process, meaning there is something that can't be copied c) "You" get split into these two bodies.

**What happens ?**

Comment: Are your first two options really mutually exclusive? Also Leibniz famously claimed there're no two same leafs in this world...

Comment: "In physics, the [no-cloning theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-cloning_theorem) states that it is impossible to create an independent and identical copy of an arbitrary unknown quantum state."

Answer (score 1):

Let's rule out 1), because whether the machine is possible or not is a matter of speculation, so we might as well adopt the speculation that allows us to consider the rest of the question.

Option 2) seems nonsense. There is no evidence that anything important about you is  entangled (I assume you mean in a quantum mechanical sense) with the rest of the Universe.

So that leaves 3). However, none of your sub-options options a) to c) seems necessary or logical. What is wrong with a fourth, d), in which there are two copies of you, each of whom thinks they are you?

Comment: If option d is true, then who am I ?

Comment: I don't understand what the if clause has to do with the remainder of your question.

Answer (score 1):

The no-cloning theorem excludes the copying of quantum states, for an introduction see [no-cloning theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-cloning_theorem).

Hence the copying of individuality as scetched by the OP's question is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

In order to answer this question , the nature of You must be established. Are you body or its parts ? Are you perceptions ? Are you feedings ? Are you choices ? Are you consciousness? Well, it turns out You are none of the above.

However , if we ignore the question of who you are ? Then , body can be copied, feelings can be copied , perceptions can be copied , choices can be copied , consciousness can be copied.
Nature does it all the time. For example - identical looking twins with almost similar nature. In many cases copies of famous personalities (almost like a body double)can be found in the world.

Whether a machine can be created to copy some or almost all attributes is debatable.

Answer (score 0):

This thought experiment challenges our notions of identity and consciousness, in the context of a framework of physical monism, which presupposes there is nothing about the self or the consciousness that isn't physical at its fundamental root. There is an unspoken final option is to reject physical monism, in favor of belief in a non-physical soul or spirit.

However, this doesn't have to be viewed as a pure hypothetical. There's a close analog in real life, which is the severing of the copus callosum, the "wires" connecting the two halves of the brain. A person can live after such an operation, but studies suggest that the two halves of the brain begin to operate as semi-independent consciousnesses. This is as would be expected from the physical monist viewpoint, but represents a challenge to more traditional ideas of an indivisible soul, as do other results mapping changes in internal mental state to observable physical changes in the brain.